Father meets son whom he never even knew he had
New Description Title: Father Meets Son Whom He Never Even Knew He Had
Plot Details:

A father meets his son whom he never even knew he had, specifically, the boy goes out of his way to look for his father and introduces himself as his son. At first, the guy is suspicious whether or not he believes what the boy told him, and he tries to push his 'son' away from him, but the son doesn't leave.
Tentative/Unsure Detail: The mother has died or the mother told the son to go and meet the father. She is only referenced to and does not really make an appearance on-screen, at least from what I remember.
Tentative/Unsure Detail: The main guy, the father, doesn't even know who the mother of his son is.
I'm not sure though if this is the main plot of the movie revolves around the whole father-and-son thing, or if it's just a sub-plot.

Character Descriptions:

The main character, the father:

has a fairly husky body type.
sports a beard/has some stubble.
Matt-Damon(face shape)+guy-from-the-street-esque characteristics. [He isn't edgy per se, nor does he have any tattoos.]

The son:

has the semblance of an emo teenager (and he most probably is one)
is quite intelligent and smart, in the scholarly and virtuous sense.
puberty-Jake-Gyllenhaal-from-2001-film-Bubble-Boy-esque dark hair [brown/black/anything dark],
just not as unruly and, you know, his hair's not standing up like an electrocuted mad scientist.
most probably has some eye bags.
Compared to Jake Gyllenhaal's shrill voice tone in the 2001 movie Bubble Boy, our guy has a noticeably lower tone of voice, but definitely not that low.
He sort of stutters in his speech, or rather, he talks anxiously and sometimes with abrupt, but not abnormal, pauses in between.


Technical Details:

The movie is definitely in color.
The movie was most likely made in-between 2004-2013.
The movie was aired in Star Movies probably close to the time when "You Don't Mess With the Zohan (2008)" was being aired, probably, during the same time the aforementioned movie was being aired, or a few year before and after it. I put this in here because I normally don't watch Star Movies or movies in general, but this was the time period when I was watching in Star Movies and was most likely the period where the movie was aired there too - a few years before and/or after 2008.
The country it was made from was most likely in the U.S. Maybe they partnered with the U.K or Canada in making it, but I'm not sure. Other than that, 100% U.S.
The language used by the actors and actresses in the movie are English.
The movie is definitely NOT ANIMATED. The characters were portrayed by real-life actors and actresses.
Speaking of actors and actresses, I don't remember this film featuring any Native Americans(Negros). The main roles were played by light-skinned/tanned people.
The movie most likely has genres of comedy, drama, and family themes. 
Although I searched through Wikipedia lists of just comedy and just drama from their 2005-2013 database list, I wasn't able to find a match. I probably just missed it though.

Other distinctive details:

This movie features a father and son plot or sub-plot, wherein, as a reminder, the father is surprised to meet a son whom he never even knew he had, and the mother barely gets any screen time, if any at all.
In one of the, what I would like to call, "confrontation scenes" between the father and son, which in this case, they did outside in the streets, the son spins out a quote from the famous Russian author Count Lev Nikolayevich Tolstoy's book, "War and Peace." This is the clearest plot detail that I remember that DEFINITELY happened. Although I do not remember what he said at all, the quote is probably about family, love, or humanity in general, something that helped him catch the attention of his father.


If it was an Indian (Malayalam) film, it would have been "Snehaveedu (http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2091412/)". Maybe it's inspired or copied from the one the OP is looking for ;)

point of order: Native Americans =/= Negroes. I think you meant the movie does not contain any African Americans

I know it's not the answer, but "Elf" certainly ticks a lot of those boxes. :)

@Steve-O You're correct, I mean that African-American actors/actresses, the dark-skinned guys, didn't play any major roles in the film, at least as I can remember. Thank you for correcting that detail. :D

@AeJey I checked out the plot synopsis of "Snehaveedu," and the part where, "One day a boy comes and meets Ajayan claiming to be his son." is definitely the plot detail that I'm looking for; however, although I've watched this movie a long time ago, I'm sure that the roles were played by American/English-speaking actors, so you can exclude Asian/Indian films. If you guys have anything else that matches this specific plot detail, feel free to put it down in the comments and I'll check it out. Thanks so much in advance again. :D
